# How to add or pre-pend hard coded data with linq resultset c#

Tags: c#, linq

suppose below query is returning City ID and City Name but if i want to `pre-pend` some hard coded data with `linq` result then how could i do it

```
var cityList = network.Continents
                      .SelectMany(continent => continent.Countries)
                      .Where(ctry => ctry.Id == "country")
                      .SelectMany(ctry =>  ctry.Cities,
                                  c => new City { Id = c.Id, Name = c.Name })
                      .ToList();
```

the above query will return data this way

```
City ID                       City Name
--------                      ------------
1                             Bombay

2                             Kolkata

3                             Delhi
```

but i want result this way

```
City ID                       City Name
---------                     -----------
0                             --Select City--

1                               Bombay

2                               Kolkata

3                               Delhi
```

so i want to add this data `0 as ID and  --Select City-- as Name` to the list which return linq query. help me with sample code. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Umm... just `Insert()` it?

```
var cityList = network.Continents
                  .SelectMany(continent => continent.Countries)
                  .Where(ctry => ctry.Id == "country")
                  .SelectMany(ctry =>  ctry.Cities,
                              c => new City { Id = c.Id, Name = c.Name })
                  .ToList();

// yup, this is what I would do...
cityList.Insert(0, new City{ Id = 0, Name = "--Select City--"});
```

Answer (score 1):

solution with `Enumerable.Concat`

```
City[] prepend = new City[] {new City { Id = 0, Name = "--Select City--"}};
IEnumerable<City> cities = network.Continents
                      .SelectMany(continent => continent.Countries)
                      .Where(ctry => ctry.Id == "country")
                      .SelectMany(ctry =>  ctry.Cities,
                                  c => new City { Id = c.Id, Name = c.Name });
var citySequence = prepend.Concat(cities);
var cityList = citySequence.ToList();
```

Comment: see this line `City[] prepend = new City[]` means for just small entry addition i need create one extra class.........does it make sense?

Comment: @Thomas, it is not an extra class, it's a extra object. since you are working with List, it is simpler to insert a new item, because List supports inserts. But if you need result as array or just IEnumerable, Concat will be useful